# How can I write unicode string to json?

Tags: python

```
def write_json(type: str, file_dir: str, ascent: int, height: int, chars: str):
    with open('result.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as make_file:
        custom_font = dict()
        custom_font["type"] = type
        custom_font["file"] = file_dir
        custom_font["ascent"] = ascent
        custom_font["height"] = height
        custom_font["chars"] = rf"{chars}"
        json_data = custom_font

        json.dump(json_data, make_file, indent="\t")
    with open('result.json', 'r') as f:
        json_data = json.load(f)

    print(json.dumps(json_data, indent="\t"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    index = 30000
    amount = 20

    c = "{}".format(hex(index))[2:]

    for i in range(amount):
        c = "{}".format(hex(index+i))[2:]
        unicode = rf"\u{c}"
        print(unicode)
        write_json("bitmap", "skill:font/assassin/blasting/1.png", 41, 160, unicode)
```

I want to write unicode string to json, but it writes excape twice.
I tried both rf"{chars}" and just chars at line 8, but it doesn't matters.

Comment: The `\u<hex>` values are what it looks like _after_ it's encoded to JSON. If you're going to pass it through a dump, it should be a literal Python representation of that value, not a Python representation _of the JSON encoding_.

Comment: To concretely describe what I mean: If you want hex ASCII character 1 encoded as JSON, that's `json.dumps('\x01')`, **not** `json.dumps(r'\u0001')`. Your _input_ should be the exact character you want to dump, not a JSON string describing that character.

Comment: thank you Charles Duffy I solved!

Comment: Great! Maybe add your solution as an answer (with the "Add an Answer" button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `c = "{}".format(hex(index+i))[2:]; unicode = rf"\u{c}"`, just use `unicode = chr(index+i)`.

The goal is for your Python string to be *a Python literal* of the value you want to encode as JSON. `"\u0001"` is a JSON representation, not a Python representation, of Unicode character 1; the Python representation of that same character is just `'\x01'`. Using `chr()` in Python 3 will jump directly to what you need.